# Get x and y coordinate of UIButton

Tags: ios, button, uibutton, tags, coordinates

I have a button called "buttonPressed". When I press the button, I need to find the x and y co-ordinates to that button. Do you have any ideas that may help me out?

```
    UIButton *circleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    circleButton.frame = rect;
    circleButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
    [circleButton addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:circleButton];

-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{

}
```

**Answer**

```
     - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
     {
       CGPoint coordinates = sender.frame.origin;
       CGFloat x = coordinates.x;
       CGFloat y = coordinates.y;
     }
```

Comment: which coordinates? where do you want to send them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you're wanting the X & Y off the sender of the action. Attach a sender parameter to your button tap method and find the frame for sender.

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    CGPoint coordinates = sender.frame.origin;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem was: (UIButton *) where I had (id). I didn't saw that :/ Lesson learned